# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() didn't give the project reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

I have many projects in my solutions (.net core).

[image]

`API` and `Web.Framework` are used by `API.IntegrationTest` project. When I compile solution, dll files of `API` and `Web.Framework` are created in `API.IntegrationTest` but while `API.IntegrationTest` is running, I can't reach those dll files. To do this, I use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` method and I'm sure and see dll files in domain folder but they don't come using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`. Is there anyone who has any theory about this scenario?

Comment: The assembly is probably not loaded into your appdomain until you access any type that comes from that assembly. Also if your `API.IntegrationTest` does not contain any compile time reference to the other assembly the references may be optimized away.